# Can we have different scenario for one api in karate?

Tags: karate

Lets say I have one api and there are different scenarios to check in that one api.So for this can we add different scenarios in one feature file without calling api again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly have multiple scenarios in one feature file.

And if you get a response back and you can do all the assertions you have in mind against this single response - you don't need to call again.  Maybe you need a single scenario.

If you are expecting all your boundary conditions and non-happy paths to be achieved without making multiple HTTP calls, I'm sorry - I don't think any framework will do that magic for you.

Comment: What I mean to say is lets say I got a response containing 3 fields in response json. Now I want 3 scenarios for 3 fields so that even if first scenario fails other remaining scenario should not skip.

Comment: `Scenario` is not meant for this: if you use a `Scenario Outline` it will run all `Example` rows even if previous ones failed.